# When clicked NSImageView, Application can't move

Tags: cocoa, events, macos, nsview, nsimageview

I create `NSToolbar` and added `NSView` on the `NSToolbar`.
`NSView` Included `NSImageView`.

When clicked `NSImageView` or `NSView` in `NSToolbar`, I can't moved application.
How can I move application when I clicked `NSView` (or `NSImageView`) on the `NSToolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear to me, but if you want to move the window with the mouse you could subclass the NSView (or NSImageView) and add

```
- (BOOL)mouseDownCanMoveWindow {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank your answer.but it' doesn't work. When I clicked NSToolbar, I can move main window. but when I clicked NSView on NSToolbar, I can't .

Comment: Are you sure you are subclassing the NSImageView, because the method I described here works for me? Override the draw function to test it. - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect { [[NSColor yellowColor] set]; NSRectFill(dirtyRect); }

Comment: I will test again about this problem. Thank you.